# Oracle graph connection issue in Spring JPA

Tags: oracle-graph

anybody have used spring JPA I am facing issue there with Oracle graph with spring jpa I am not able to connect with Oracle Graph DB.Expected is it should be able to create all the tables automatically annotated by @Entity

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the database connection does not work, can you share more details?    After that you can create graph from data in relational tables (not the other way around).  The data is typically in relational tables and then you create a graph from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a connection to the Oracle DB is done similarly regardless of which features you use. The thing you need to do is give the DB user additional privileges. [Check the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/23.1/spgdg/installing-pl-sql-packages-oracle-database.html) for guidance.